# Where to store access token from external API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, jwt, vscode-extensions

I have a TypeScript Node app that runs as an extension to VS Code and makes REST calls to an external API.  I make a POST to this external API with user credentials and the API returns a JWT.  I then use that JWT to call other API endpoints.  I'm not sure where to store the JWT.  Originally, I had a singleton in memory, but I've been reading around the web that using singletons is bad practice.  One of the reasons being that it causes dependency problems for testing.  Would it be advisable to have something like a UserService layer that writes the token to the user profile on their local machine and read it from there every time I want to make a request?  This solution would allow inversion of control since I can inject the UserService into the controllers since it's not a singleton.  I just want to ensure I'm using best software practices.

Comment: Why don't just store it in memory, as a `UserService` parameter? You might also want to use some sort of a backup storage, to retrieve the token from there in case of plugin crash/restart.

Comment: @MaximMazurok is that the best practice?  I could have a getToken method in the UserService that gets the token if it's not undefined in memory, otherwise it would retrieve it from storage on the user's local machine.

Comment: Well, in my current project I use something similar, storing JWT in session storage and I think that practice is pretty good. Also, make sure to erase it from backup when (and if) it gets expired. You might also want to use `rxjs/store` for in-memory data storage and retrieval.